# asp.net core routing - get URL parameters that include slashes

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to have a route in asp.net core that returns the entire path of the URL as a variable for my IActionResult.

For example:

1. With https://example.com/services, the *path* variable should be equal
   to "services"
2. With https://example.com/services/cleaning, the *path* variable should
   be equal to "services/cleaning"
3. With https://example.com/services/painting, the *path* variable should
   be equal to "services/painting"
4. With https://example.com/services/painting/interior, the *path* variable should
   be equal to "services/painting/interior"

I have only the following route in my Startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Redirect",
        "{*path}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", path = string.Empty }
    );
});
```

This works for example 1, but is ignored for examples 2, 3, and 4.

How can I get the route to work, regardless of the number of slashes?

---

**UPDATE:** My issue was that I had decorated my controller with a route definition.   I removed that and everything works fine.

Comment: If you're looking for the request path, that is probably in the [`HttpContext.Request`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/DefaultHttpContext.cs#L108) object. There is a [`.Path`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpRequest.cs#L54) property that looks promising.

Comment: @DavidPine the issue I am having is that in Examples 2, 3, 4 I get a blank page.  I am guessing because it is not finding what it feels is a valid route.

Comment: That is a correct assumption

Comment: Hence the question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that I had decorated my controller with a route definition.   I removed that and everything works fine.